# Why can the third host receive dataflow between host no.1 and host no.2?(Three hosts are all virtual machines installed in VMware with NAT mode)

Tags: sockets, networking, vmware, pcap, tcpdump

I installed three operating systems(let's say 3 hosts) in VMware, all with NAT mode. 3 hosts are named centos, centos 1,centos 2.(As the pic shows below)
[3 hosts in VMware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jftvq.png)

The first host's IP address is 192.168.248.132, the second is 192.168.248.136, and we don't need to know third host's IP because it's not related to this issue.
I typed the command "ping 192.168.248.136", and the output on the screen is:

```
PING 192.168.248.136 (192.168.248.136) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.248.136: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.435 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.248.136: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.313 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.248.136: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.385 ms
```

This means ping command has succeeded and host no.2(whose IP addr is 192.168.248.136) has received ICMP and replied.
Meanwhile, I typed the command "tcpdump -i ens33" in host no.3. If everything had worked correctly, host no.3 would not have received any data between host no.1 and host no.2, because ICMP is neither broadcast nor multicast, so only host no.1 and 2 can send and receive. Also, host no.3's network interface is not promiscuous mode, so it can only receive it's own frame. The output from host no.3 below can show it is not promiscuous mode.

```
[root@localhost usr]# ifconfig
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.248.137  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.248.255
        inet6 fe80::b488:bc2c:3770:a95f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:0d:dc:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 351081  bytes 512917768 (489.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34947  bytes 2166260 (2.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

flag is 4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>, "PROMISC" is not mentioned, so it is not promiscuous mode.

However, after I typed "tcpdump -i ens33" in host no.3, something appeared on the screen:

```
06:28:11.511233 IP 192.168.248.132 > 192.168.248.136: ICMP echo request, id 3137, seq 5, length 64
06:28:11.511503 IP 192.168.248.136 > 192.168.248.132: ICMP echo reply, id 3137, seq 5, length 64
```

Host no.3 received the dataflow between no.1 and 2, and this was supposed to be sent to no.2, but no.3 received it.

So here comes the question, why can host no.3 receive packet which was not supposed to be sent to it?

Answer (score 0):

tcpdump by default activates "promiscuous mode" making it able to see anything on the network it is connected to (even if not explicitly sent to it).

the three hosts seem to be connected to a virtual switch that do not isolate the hosts from each other.